# React: Get meta content by name

Tags: reactjs

I'm storing my CSRF token as `<meta name="_csrf"  th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>` in my head. With Javascript, I would just use a query selector to grab the property. On React, I have no idea and can't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get meta tags by name like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("META")[1].content
```

[image: getting meta tags]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you.